# How to insert one column value as static in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, typeorm

I have a table `business_data` with below structure

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default              | Extra |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
| id              | varchar(36)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                 |       |
| monthlyDate     | date          | NO   |     | 1970-01-01           |       |
| transactionId   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL                 |       |
| transactionType | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL                 |       |
| number          | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL                 |       |
| description     | text          | NO   |     | NULL                 |       |
| amount          | decimal(20,2) | NO   |     | NULL                 |       |
| active          | tinyint(4)    | NO   |     | 1                    |       |
| createdAt       | datetime(6)   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) |       |
| updatedAt       | datetime(6)   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) |       |
| version         | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL                 |       |
| businessId      | varchar(36)   | YES  |     | NULL                 |       |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
```

I am using a function to insert data into this table as

```
 saveBusinessData(dbConnection: any) {

        let data = '[["32447e98-6a8b-40d0-a70f-157739089be1",666,"2020-08-26","some description",4,"4565","Bill",true,1]]'
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

            if (data.length > 0) {
                let qry =
                    "INSERT INTO business_data (id, businessId, amount,date,description,number,transactionId, transactionType, active, version,monthlyDate) VALUES ?";

                dbConnection.query(qry, [data], async function (err: any, res: any) {
                    if (err) {

                        reject(err);
                    }


                    resolve(true)

                });

            }
        });

    }
```

There is column `'monthlyDate'`. This date is not included in the data. For one `saveBusinessData` function call there will be multiple rows & values will be different but `monthlyDate` will be the same for one function call. So instead of it adding it into data, I want a way I can pass monthlyDate in query separately so that I don't have to modify the data to have `monthlyDate` value.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: *but monthlyDate will be the same for one function call.* ... but it differs for different calls. So this "optimization" makes no sense.

Comment: Yes but there can be 1000 records and the date will be the same & the date is not included in data so I don't want to modify data. so that's why I am looking for that solution

Comment: *So instead of it adding it into data* Why don't yo want to add it to the data?

Comment: I don't want to modify the data because it's an array of records & it can be in 1000's. and date will be same so i want to add into query.

Comment: What interface uses a single `?` for a list of values?

Comment: Simply **Append** Date To **data** array.

Answer (score 1):

### Approach 1: Triggers

One way of achieving this is using a database trigger. A trigger will be executed whenever an action is performed. You can configure the database to fire a trigger before inserting. For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER inserted before INSERT ON hospital
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.monthly_date = NOW()/1000;
    --- Insert your logic here ^^
END$$
```

So then when you insert into the table, the monthly row column will be automatically inserted with the current timestamp.

```
insert into hospital (name, bed_count) values ('Name', 2353);
```

Result:

```
+------+-----------+----+--------------+
| name | bed_count | id | monthly_date |
+------+-----------+----+--------------+
| Name |      2353 |  3 |  20200907170 |
+------+-----------+----+--------------+
```

---

### Approach 2: Update Statement

Since you're storing the created time, you can fire an update statement on the table for rows created during the particular interval of time. I'm not sure how to do this in the framework you're using. It's equivalent to running the following sql:

```
update table set monthly_date = d3 where created_date > d1 and created_date < d2;
```

I don't recommend the second approach unless the created_date column is indexed. This could also update rows that you didn't insert.

Answer (score 0):

One way, is to add to all your arrays a date in mysql format to all "rows" and insert that resulting array

because data is a string i added `let arr = JSON.parse(data);` so that `unshift`can work.

This runs all in memory and should be quick with a 1000 or so elements

```
saveBusinessData(dbConnection: any) {

    let data = '[["32447e98-6a8b-40d0-a70f-157739089be1",666,"2020-08-26","some description",4,"4565","Bill",true,1]]'
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        if (data.length > 0) {
           let arr = JSON.parse(data);
           let index;
           for (index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) {

                arr[index].unshift(date.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
           }
            let qry =
                "INSERT INTO business_data (monthlyDate,id, businessId, amount,date,description,number,transactionId, transactionType, active, version,monthlyDate) VALUES ?";

            dbConnection.query(qry, [arr], async function (err: any, res: any) {
                if (err) {

                    reject(err);
                }


                resolve(true)

            });

        }
    });

}
```